# Fixing 1064 SQL Error Importing Database into Wampserver

Tags: php, mysql, database, wampserver

When importing my 636MB database into Wampserver I get the below error. What is interesting is that I have max execution time set to 5000 in (php.ini). I have also tried numerous import methods and compression types all with the same results: MySql Console, PhpMyAdmin Console, BigDump, zip, gzip and finally using config.inc.php to upload a specified directory. Thank you for all help, suggestions & advice.

**Current Settings:**
**php.ini:**
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M

**config.inc.php:**
// maximum execution time in seconds (0 for no limit)
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;

**my.ini:**
max_allowed_packet = 200M

```
MySQL said: 
1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '<br />
Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in <b' Ã  la ligne 141

Error
SQL query: 

INSERT INTO `log_url_info` (`url_id`, `url`, `referer`) VALUES
(2287337, 'http://www.website12345.com/sendfriend/product/send/id/44894/', NULL),
(2287338, 'http://www.website12345.com/sendfriend/product/send/id/44894/', NULL),
(2287339, 'http://www.website12345.com/sendfriend/product/send/id/44894/', NULL),
(2287340, 'http://www.website12345.com/catalog/category/view/id/66', NULL),
(2287341, 'http://www.website12345.com/catalog/category/view/id/718?multi_select_color_filter=2040', NULL),
(2287342, 'http://www.website12345.com/catalog/category/view/id/879?price=1000-2000', NULL),
(2287343, 'http://www.website12345.com/catalog/category/view/id/152?

limit=15&manufacturer=351&mode=list&multi_select_finish_filter=2602&multi_select_material_filter=2060&price=-1000', NULL),
(2287344, 'http://www.website12345.com/sendfriend/product/send/id/30583/', NULL),
(2287345, 'http://www.website12345.com/catalog/category/view/id/673?multi_select_finish_filter=2025', NULL),
(2287346, 'ht[...]
```

Comment: Those are two separate errors. You might want to concentrate on the sql syntax error first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! I had to truncate & optimize log tables and select "Disable foreign key checks" upon exporting. And the database imported! No other changes required.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have some syntax errors on your SQL query try to check that first.

I have managed to import an 800mb Database using command line.

**Try**:

```
mysql -p -u username -h 127.0.0.1 database < database.sql
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Can you give me some direction on fixing these types of syntax errors and all of what's involved? I am not sure exactly were to begin? Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

The `max_execution_time` for phpMyAdmin is now controlled by the alias definition that lives in

```
\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf
```

WAMPServer 2.5 version

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
# Require local
#
# by
#
# Require all granted
#

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Note the use of these 4 parameters

```
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
```

You may need to amend `upload_max_filesize` and `max_execution_time`

Amend where required then restart Apache

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Service _Restart Service
```

Now PHP will pay attention to these new parameters when you are running phpMyAdmin.