# how to import database in phpmyadmin if size is Large

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp

in php.ini i tried to change like this but no use

`post_max_size=1280M
 upload_max_filesize=1280M 
max_execution_time = 300`

please give me a solution , my database size is 568MB

Comment: you can use mysql dump as alternative...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixing 1064 SQL Error Importing Database into Wampserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408592/fixing-1064-sql-error-importing-database-into-wampserver)

Answer (score 1):

you can't import large database in phpmyadmin by just changing the `php.ini`

[Use Bigdump to dump database](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/)

Answer (score 0):

Use command line

```
mysql -u username -p password dbname < yourdatabase.sql
```

where yourdatabase.sql is your sql file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bigdump (http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/). On shared hostings you mostly don't have access to an SSH shell, so using bigdump, you can also do this without ssh access.

Comment: Please thumbs up helpful answers

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your file to the web server and use the UploadDir phpMyAdmin directive to make this file available.

See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=uploaddir#cfg_UploadDir